# Cron job every minute?

Tags: php, unix, cron

I have a cron job running that executes a PHP file which checks a MySQL database for a change. I have this script running every minute but it's very simply query.

Still, is running a cron job like this every minute going to be too hard on the server? Is there a better approach to what I'm doing?

Comment: we don't know what (more important why) your doing, so cant answer that. except for a shared host, i cant imagine any server having an issue

Comment: I'm running a statement like "SELECT id FROM user WHERE change='true'. It's not important what happens when it finds a good match because that won't be every minute at all... I just want to know if the simple select statement is too much in and of itself.

Comment: unlikely to be an issue. Based on the little information provided

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the query, if it's SQL related only, consider a **MySQL event**. But it depends on what it does. If PHP code is required to interact with it... events won't help. If it just does some updates in MySQL *(like expired user sessions and removing unconfirmed user accounts)*... an event will do.

Running every minute is not hard on the server, it depends on what it does. `microtime()` execution of the script and log it to a text file with `register_shutdown_function()` *(you can also `memory_get_peak_usage()`)*. **See how long it takes, how much memory it consumes... that will tell you how hard it is on the server.**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply @CodeAngry. You provided some good functions to look into so I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

A simple query like that shouldn't be an issue... most PHP pages make many more calls, and the server can be processing many requests at once. Unless it's a beast of a query, you'll be fine.